# Need help building a debug lxml for python27 on windows

Tags: python, lxml

I am debugging another dll imported by a script that uses lxml.  I need to create an objectify_d.pyd and etree_d.pyd from the lxml project.  I successfully built these by following the build instructions here: http://lxml.de/build.html but using this command:

```
python setup.py build --debug --static
```

I tried just doing:

```
python setup.py build --debug
```

but that didn't work.

The build appears to succeed.  An objectify_d.pyd and etree_d.pyd are created.  Using these files (by copying them to c:/python27/lib/site-packages/lxml/) and running a debug python build I get the following when attempting to import:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[83669 refs]
```

I then ran python in the debugger and see that the call to LoadLibraryEx is failing (returns NULL).  The GetLastError() call returns 126 which means it can't find the dll.  The path is correct.  So I expect it is not finding a dependent DLL. I'm running this on the machine that built it, so it isn't the runtime library that is missing.

Here is what was printed when I built the dll:

```
</c/lxml/lxml-2.3 Trunk>
$python setup.py build --debug --static
Building lxml version 2.3.
Building with Cython 0.15.1.
ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt
Building against libxml2/libxslt in one of the following directories:
  ..\iconv-1.9.2.win32\lib
  ..\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib
  ..\libxmlsec-1.2.18.win32\lib
  ..\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\lib
  ..\zlib-1.2.5\lib
  c:\python27
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'src/lxml\lxml.etree.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'lxml.etree' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Od /MDd /W3 /GS- /Z7 /D_DEBUG -I..\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include -I..\libxml2-2.7.8.win 32\include -I..\libxmlsec-1.2.18.win32\include -I..\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\include -I..\zlib-1.2.5\include -I..\ -IC:\python27\include -IC:\python27\PC /TcC:\lxml \lxml-2.3\src\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w DEBUG
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'DEBUG', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'DEBUG' ignored
lxml.etree.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:no /DEBUG /pdb:None /LIBPATH:..\iconv-1.9.2.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\l ibxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\libxmlsec-1.2.18.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\zlib-1.2.5\lib /LIBPATH:c:\python27 /LIBPATH:C:\p ython27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\python27\PCbuild libxslt_a.lib libexslt_a.lib libxml2_a.lib iconv_a.lib zlib.lib WS2_32.lib /EXPORT:initetree build\temp.win32-2.7\Debu g\src/lxml\lxml.etree.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\etree_d.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\etree_d.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\etree_d.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\etree_d.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\etree_d.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
lxml.etree.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _xmlFree imported
lxml.etree.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _xmlMalloc imported
lxml.etree.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _xsltDocDefaultLoader imported
lxml.etree.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _xsltLibxsltVersion imported
zlib.lib(adler32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(crc32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(deflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzclose.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzlib.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzread.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzwrite.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inffast.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inftrees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(trees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(zutil.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\etree_d.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\etree_d.pyd;2 skipping 'src/lxml\lxml.objectify.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'lxml.objectify' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Od /MDd /W3 /GS- /Z7 /D_DEBUG -I..\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include -I..\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\include -I..\libxmlsec-1.2.18.win32\include -I..\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\include -I..\zlib-1.2.5\include -I..\ -IC:\python27\include -IC:\python27\PC /TcC:\lxml\lxml-2.3\src\lxml\lxml.objectify.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\lxml.objectify.obj -w DEBUG
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'DEBUG', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'DEBUG' ignored
lxml.objectify.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:no /DEBUG /pdb:None /LIBPATH:..\iconv-1.9.2.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\libxmlsec-1.2.18.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\libxslt-1.1.26.win32\lib /LIBPATH:..\zlib-1.2.5\lib /LIBPATH:c:\python27 /LIBPATH:C:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\python27\PCbuild libxslt_a.lib libexslt_a.lib libxml2_a.lib iconv_a.lib zlib.lib WS2_32.lib /EXPORT:initobjectify build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\lxml.objectify.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\objectify_d.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\objectify_d.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\objectify_d.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\objectify_d.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\objectify_d.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
zlib.lib(adler32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(crc32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(deflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzclose.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzlib.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzread.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(gzwrite.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inffast.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(inftrees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(trees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
zlib.lib(zutil.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlib.pdb' was not found with '..\zlib-1.2.5\lib\zlib.lib' or at 'C:\lxml\lxml-2.3\zlib.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win32-2.7\Debug\src/lxml\objectify_d.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\objectify_d.pyd;2
```

Some other info:

- I'm using the lxml-2.3 code, since that is what my app has been using.
- I'm running on a Windows 7 box using python27 (32 bit)

I'd be content if someone could just provide me with a debug build of lxml for windows that works, or point me to an explanation of how to use release python dlls mixed with debug dlls.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building in Cygwin environment and then trying to run in Windows? Try building in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to build a debug version of lxml, but it almost certainly won't work. From what I remember, the setup scripts shipped with lxml were made to build a release version only.

You can take advantage of this and simply generate the debug symbols (.pdb) for the release version. The procedure is fairly complex, but here's an overview:

1. Install the necessary build tools (Visual Studio, Powershell).
2. Get the source code of lxml's dependencies (libxml2, libxslt, iconv, zlib).
3. Build these dependencies and generate their debug symbols.
4. Download the version of lxml that you want to debug (e.g. 3.7.0).
5. Tweak lxml's setup.py to point to the statically built dependencies.
6. Patch distutils to make it think that your specific Visual Studio version must be used, instead of the one that was used to build your Python interpreter.
7. Build lxml and generate its debug symbols.
8. Package the whole thing in a wheel file.

That's it! :) I guess that it would probably be more reasonable to link to the [detailed procedure](https://benbernardblog.com/how-to-build-lxml-and-get-its-debug-symbols-on-windows/).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the post.